# Call osascript through perl in OSX 10.9 doesn't work anymore

Tags: macos, perl, applescript, osascript

I'm writing an application for Mac (OSX, **not** iOS). 
The installation runs a perl script which contains some "osascript" call, for example:

```
$res = qx(osascript -e 'launch application "MyApp"');
```

Or:

```
$res = qx(osascript -e 'tell application "System event" to make login item at end with properties {path:".... .app", hidden: false}');
```

and more...

I have two Mac machines, one with OSX 10.9 and other with OSX 10.7.

When I'm running the installation on OSX 10.7 - All works good.

When I'm running the installation on OSX 10.9 - the call to osascript doesn't work (all of them, not only one). I tried to run only the osascript command in terminal, and it works!

The installation process done from user (not admin) but ask for admin permission during the installation.

Someone know what have been changed in the new OSx?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: I don't get error, but nothing happened. Maybe is it a permission issue?

Comment: Check the exit code by adding `print $? >> 8, "\n";` immediately after the `qx`.

Comment: Works for me on 10.9.1.